# Regex to filter challenging string, having a dash, spaces, numbers and certain words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

For my search panel, I must filter a sting that looks like:

```
'4dan-7kyu' or '4dan - 7kyu' or '10kyu' or '10 kyu' or '2dan' or '2 dan' or  '4-7'  or '4 - 7'  or  '10'
```

#### Allowed are only:

1. Numbers from `1-10`;
2. Words, that are NOT case sensitive, includes: `dan`, `kyu`, `дан`, `кью`;
3. Dash (not more than one AND never at the beginning of the string, never `-10kyu` or never `-10`);
4. Space (not more than once BUT never at the beginning  of the string);

I was thinking of something like this but it never worked fully for me:

`/([1-9]|10)\s-\s|dan|kyu|дан|кью/i`

What is the correct way of wring such Regex?

**EDIT 1:**

1. Space (not more than once BUT never at the beginning  of the string)

   Invalid Examples: `4dan___-___7kyu` or `_4dan_-_7kyu`

   Valid Examples: `4dan-7kyu` and `4dan - 7kyu` and `4 dan - 7kyu` and `4 dan - 7 kyu`

**EDIT 2:**

More invalid examples:
    `12dan-7kyu` or `12dan-11kyu`

Comment: Surely by your own rules `4 - 7` is invalid (rule 4)?

Comment: I guess he means that you shouldn't have 2 white space characters next to each other. But `\s-\s` should be fine still.

Comment: Please add some examples of valid and invalid strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that's:

```
/(^([1-9]|10)\s*$)
|
(^([1-9]|10)\s?-\s?([1-9]|10)\s*$)
|
(^([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s*$)
|
(^([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s?-\s?([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s*$)/ixu
```

here's PHP sample:

```
$rgData   = ['12', '20dan', ' 1kyu - 4kyu   ', '1kyu - 4kyu  ', 
             '1 kyu - 4 kyu', '1 kyu-4 kyu','4dan-7kyu', '4dan - 7kyu', 
             '10kyu', '10 kyu', '2dan', '2 dan', '4-7', '4 - 7', '10'];
$sPattern = '/(^([1-9]|10)\s*$)
             |
             (^([1-9]|10)\s?-\s?([1-9]|10)\s*$)
             |
             (^([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s*$)
             |
             (^([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s?-\s?([1-9]|10)\s?(dan|kyu|дан|кью)\s*$)/ixu';
var_dump(array_filter($rgData, function($sItem) use ($sPattern)
{
   return preg_match($sPattern, $sItem, $rgMatches);
}));//first 3 not matched
```

P.S. Greetings to martial arts colleague!

Comment: Interesting example but if you enter `$rgData   = ['12', '20dan'];` it makes no difference, your example let it through, when it shouldn't!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - yes, did not mentioned `^` and `$`. To be more specific, added different cases. thank you.

Comment: it's much much better, thank you!! But it doesn't let the valid entry, which is `1 kyu - 4 kyu` or `1 kyu-4 kyu`. Can you fix it so it matches also that?

Comment: And more, if possible don't drop `_1kyu-4kyu` just make it be there but formatted to `1kyu-4kyu`

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev in fact, I was just making that edit (I mentioned that in 2-nd part I allow space between number and string while in 4-th not)

Comment: Your Regex is just amazing, thank you Alma!! The only thing it doesn't do - it kills `1kyu - 4kyu_` or `1kyu - 4kyu__` or `_1kyu - 4kyu`, when it's better to format it just to `1kyu - 4kyu` or to `1kyu-4kyu`. It wasn't on the question initially. So if you can fix it - great, if not - it's already way to cool!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - `_` symbol is the only allowed in such cases?

Comment: It's a space, I can't write space so I replaced it with _

Comment: If `_` is a space, then why `_1kyu - 4kyu` should match? (You've mentioned that above)

Comment: Imagine you want to filter people from 1kyu to 4kyu and then you type instead of `1kyu - 4kyu` you type `_1kyu - 4kyu`? The query shouldn't be just deleted (ideally) but be reformatted to just having no space, like `1kyu - 4kyu`. Same with `1kyu -___4kyu`.
I could achieve this the other way if it's hard to make such exception.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I've added (now one or zero `_` could be at start and zero or more `_` allowed at end. Also included `_` in space group (i.e. `1dan_-_2_dan` will match). Replacing is not a matter of match - you'll need to replace it in your code.

Comment: My friend, that underscoreline is a SPACE not _. So litteraly it shouldn't match `1kyu - 4kyu__` but `1kyu - 4kyu[space][space]`

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev why then you posted (in question) that `Invalid Examples: 4dan___-___7kyu or _4dan_-_7kyu ` but here (above) - you want match: `The only thing it doesn't do - it kills 1kyu - 4kyu_ or 1kyu - 4kyu__ or _1kyu - 4kyu` (last sample is invalid I think)

Comment: Because I was wrong at the very beginning saying that it shouldn't match it! I should have just said it must just reformat it. It's my bad! You did everything correctly!! Just remove _ to match from your last example (previous one is good) and it's great!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev got it. Edited (now zero or more spaces may be at the and, `_` removed, no spaces at start)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev this is a secret dzen-regex technique :p

Comment: Thanks to you all guys, for your amazing answers!! I would accept all of your 3 answers, if I could but as Alma was the first who  provided really working example, I will have to accept Alma's answer!

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your requirements well, you can try this regex:

```
'((?!(?:[^'\s]*\s[^'\s]*){2,}'|(?:[^'-]*-[^'-]*){2,}')(?:(?:[1-9]|10)\s?-?(?:dan|kyu|дан|кью)?-?)*)'
```

[See demo on regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/hA2sZ0)

The negative lookahead at the beginning makes sure there are no two or more spaces, or dashes in the string.

Then, just have the possible combinations in the matching group, and capture everything to get the string without quotes. You can also use a lookahead and lookbehind to avoid having to capture.

```
(?<=')(?!(?:[^'\s]*\s[^'\s]*){2,}'|(?:[^'-]*-[^'-]*){2,}')(?:(?:[1-9]|10)\s?-?(?:dan|kyu|дан|кью)?-?)*(?=')
```

**EDIT:**

As per updates, you could perhaps try this regex:

```
^(?:(?:[1-9]|10)(?![0-9])) ?(?:(?:dan|kyu|дан|кью) ?)?(?:-? ?(?:(?:[1-9]|10)(?![0-9])) ?(?:(?:dan|kyu|дан|кью) ?)?)*$
```

Comment: Jerry, very nice but how about matching `4dan - 7kyu` and without quotes (it was just for example)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Is the whole string `4dan - 7kyu`? If so, you can drop the quotes completely and use anchors instead, by putting `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. Also, this string will not match since there are 2 spaces in it.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Awesome! :D

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev It's okay, I had to leave earlier to have lunch and couldn't see your comments during this time, so it's only fair. :)

Comment: I found one more bug in your example :D. If you type `11dan-11kyu` then it's fine but if you go and type `10dan-11kyu`, then it let's it through when it mustn't ;)

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Lol, my fault. I put the 'fix' in the first part and not the second. There should be a neg. lookahead in the repeating part xD [fixed](http://www.regex101.com/r/aV3yE7).

Comment: Jerry, if I wanted your regex to work just as it is right now but also let user enter - (dash), for getting specific results. Not changing anything in your regex just letting user input also a single dash?

Comment: You mean adding a single dash to the list of valid inputs? Sure, you can add `^-$|` at the beginning to allow only a dash or `^\s*-\s*$|` to allow trailing spaces.

Comment: Yes, right! Missed `$`, thanks!! Pretty soon spend more time reading thoroughly through regex docs! Could you please take a look at my last question, no one can answer it?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev No problem! I'm more better at Tcl but I guess the logic can be transferred to PHP if I manage to find the algorithm. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 4):

```
\b(?<!-)(10|[1-9])(?: ?(dan|kyu|дан|кью))?(?: ?- ?(10|[1-9])(?: ?(dan|kyu|дан|кью))?)?\b
```

## [See the captures.](http://rubular.com/r/neusYyUGEW)

I created the regex above, but it's not too readable, so if you put it to code you can make it more understandable for "the next guy" (I noticed you have `preg-replace` as a tag, so I'm assuming PHP):

```
$numbers = '(10|[1-9])';
$words = '(dan|kyu|дан|кью)';
$seperators = ' ?- ?';

$regex =
  '~\b'.
    '(?<!-)'.
    $numbers.
    '(?:'.
      ' ?'.
      $words.
    ')?'.
    '(?:'.
      $seperators.
      $numbers.
      '(?:'.
        ' ?'.
        $words.
      ')?'.
    ')?'.
  '\b~';

$string = "'12dan-7kyu' or '12dan-11kyu' or '_4dan_-_7kyu' or '4 dan - 7kyu' or '4 dan - 7 kyu' or '4dan___-___7kyu' or '4dan-7kyu' or '4dan - 7kyu' or '10kyu' or '10 kyu' or '2dan' or '2 dan' or  '4-7'  or '4 - 7'  or  '10'  ";

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

## [See it run.](http://glot.io/php/31464c9f5f8d0db1146456864f62d4c5)

Comment: Wow! You really got correctly what I was saying to Alma! Also amazing, ohall!! Works 100% precise!!

Comment: Ohaal, your example is most beautiful! Thanks to you all guys, for your amazing answers!! I would accept all of your 3 answers, if I could but as Alma was the first who  provided really working example, I will have to accept Alma's answer!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a slight modification in your RegEx to:

```
/((10|[1-9])(\s?-?\s?)(dan|kyu|дан|кью)?(\s?-?\s?)(([10|[1-9])(\s?-?\s?)(dan|kyu|дан|кью)?)?)/i
```

This uses your original RegEx but makes the white space and hyphen optional between numbers and dan or kyu and then has another lot of optional white space and hyphens and then optionally repeats.

I've also swapped the [1-9]|10 part around to stop it grabbing the 1 and moving on.